# Azure Mobile Services Login Jwt Invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, jwt, azure-mobile-services

I am using the Azure Mobile Services library and attempting to create a custom identity provider. I am running the server in Azure. I've created a custom login controller which issues JWTs upon successful login, but the generated JWTs appear to be invalid (signature fails to validate on jwt.io (using the signing key from Kudu), and server rejects the tokens as invalid when used to authenticate). The server-side code is below:

```
public TenantAuthController()
{
   _serviceContext = new MobileServiceContext();
   _signingKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY");
   var website = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME");
   _audience = $"https://{website}/";
   _issuer = $"https://{website}/";
}

[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] TenantLoginRequest request)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.TenantName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Password)) return BadRequest();
   (var valid, var tenant) = ValidateAuthRequest(request);
   if (!valid) return Unauthorized();

   var claims = new[]
   {
      new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, $"{tenant.Id}")
   };

   var token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(claims, _signingKey, _audience, _issuer, TimeSpan.FromDays(365)); // TODO Token refresh

   return Ok(
      new TenantLoginResponse
      {
         Tenant = tenant,
         Token = token.RawData,
      }
   );
}
```

I have authentication enabled on the Azure App Service and I've confirmed through remote debugging that the signing key is correct. Is there anything I'm doing wrong in my controller or configuration that would cause the jwt to be invalid?

Answer (score 0):

If the token will not parse on JWT.IO, it is invalid. It appears you are attempting to encrypt a value that is not the bearer token. From you code, it seems like you are trying to encrypt your "Tenant ID". The tenant is like subscription name in azure, and is not related to the token.

What is in AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken()? Is this custom code, or MSFT code? It seems like this is where your problem is coming from...

Comment: AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken() is a Microsoft provided function in the Azure Mobile Services authentication library.

Comment: Also, the tenant id is a user-specific value used for authentication. As far as I'm aware, I can set the subject claim value to an application-specific value, correct? It's used to track the authenticated tenant for the jwt. CreateToken() returns a JwtSecurityToken, which handles all of the encryption.